# SCJP Sierra Bates Chapter 2 Question 2 Default constructor calls

Tags: scjp, default-constructor

Background info
I have a query regarding a questions from Sierra & Bates, SCJP v6 book. Namely Chapter 2 question 2. The answer given is that the "compilation fails". However when I tried this in neBeans, the code compiled and ran without error. It also returned a output of "D" which was not one of the alternatives. There are some other discussions on this same question in various forums, regarding the need to insert super() etc. However none seem to have recognised it can compile.

Question
1. I expected the constructor "Bottom2(String s)...to have called the super constructor "Top(String s)...". In which case the output would have been "BD" (which happens to be an option for the question. Why does the "Top(String s)..." not get called. 
2. As there is a Top constructor then would the default compiler constructor still be implicitly created. ie in effect a "Top() {}" constructor which can be called by "Bottom2(String s)". This not how I understood this to happen - ie the compiler only creates this default if no other constructor is created.
3. Is there and error in this question, or is this a carry over question from the Java 5 version and somehow in Java 6 the compiler can now handle this.
4. Could netBeans have a means to "solve" the compiler problem. This is quite important as I am studying for the SCJP and I find not all the questions can be duplicated in netBeans. In which case I may learn to believe some code works when (for exam purposes) it does not.

Code included for ease of reference.

```
class Top { 
    public Top(String s) { System.out.print("B"); } 
} 

public class Bottom2 extends Top { 
    public Bottom2(String s) { System.out.print("D"); } 
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        new Bottom2("C"); 
        System.out.println(" "); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you have typed in the code exactly as it appears in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Top` doesn't have a default constructor (a default constructor is a public constructor *with empty argument list*. Therefore, the constructor of `Bottom2` must explicitly invoke the super constructor (and pass its argument), but doesn't, and hence compilation fails.

Indeed, eclipse helios says:

> Implicit super constructor Top() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

and javac says:

> ```
> cannot find symbol
> symbol  : constructor Top()
> location: class tools.Top
>     public Bottom2(String s) { System.out.print("D"); }
>                              ^
> ```

Are you really sure you have tried the same code in Netbeans?

Comment: Hi Thanks for raising the issue of the code. I've gone back and checked this again. Somehwere in my experimenting on the sequence I've deleted the "extends Top" on the 5th line. Teach me to study late at night after the wife and kids have gone to sleep. Once re-inserted it fails to compile as it would obviously need a "public Top(){};" default constructor to function properly.